# Declaring list and map variable values in terraform.tfvars

Tags: variables, terraform

I recently moved over the values for my variables within my terraform code to terraform.tfvars. I am now getting an error that is due to how I am declaring my list and map variables. The code where I am getting the error is replicated below:

```
image_id             = var.web_amis[var.region]
```

this is how I have these variables specified in terraform.tfvars:

```
web_amis                      = ["ami-0dacb0c129b49f529", "ami-00068cd7555f543d5", ]
```

this is the error code I am getting:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on autoscaling.tf line 3, in resource "aws_launch_configuration" "web_lc":
   3:   image_id             = var.web_amis[var.region]
    |----------------
    | var.region is "us-east-2"
    | var.web_amis is tuple with 2 elements

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a number
is required.
```

[image: A screenshot of the error message given above, showing that Terraform has highlighted the var.region portion as being the problematic part of the source code snippet.]

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to access a list element with a non index key instead of by position.

What you probably want instead is to have your `web_amis` variable be a map that is keyed by the region name:

#### main.tf

```
variable "region" {}
variable "web_amis" {}

resource "foo_bar" "baz" {
  # ...
  image_id = var.web_amis[var.region]
}
```

#### terraform.tfvars

```
web_amis = {
  us-east-2 = "ami-0dacb0c129b49f529"
  us-west-2 = "ami-00068cd7555f543d5"
}
```

---

But, this is a very old school and inelegant way of doing things with Terraform nowadays. Instead you could use the [`aws_ami` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html) to look up the AMI for the region based on filters such as tags or the name of the AMI.

A basic example is given in the [`aws_instance` resource documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html):

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```